# Fastapi Testclient not able to send POST request using form-data

Tags: unit-testing, http-post, fastapi, starlette, httpx

Currently I am doing Unit Testing in Fastapi using `from fastapi.testclient import TestClient`

```
def test_login_api_returns_token(session,client):
    form_data = {
        "username": "mike@gmail.com",
        "password": "mike"
    }
    response = client.post(  
        "/api/login", 
        data=form_data,
        headers={"content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
        # headers={"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    )
    result = response.json()
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

I am supposed to get token as response which I am getting when I run the fastapi application but not able to proceed with Unit Testing with the same.

Example of postman request for the same

[image]

How do I make sure form-data is being sent from TestClient?

api/login.py

```
@router.post("/login")
async def user_login(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(), session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    user = authenticated_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, session)
    user = user[0]
    if not user:
        raise token_exception()
    token_expires = timedelta(minutes=120)
    token = create_access_token(username=user.username, user_id=user.id, expires_delta=token_expires)
    token_exp = jwt.decode(token, SECRET, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
    return {
        "status_code": status.HTTP_200_OK,
        "data":{
            "username": user.username,
            "token": token,
            "expiry": token_exp['exp'],
            "user_id": user.id
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What headers are set in your postman request?

Comment: I had missed adding login route in fixture, hence was getting 404 not found in response.

Answer (score 3):

Try set the header to Content-Type form-data like

```
def test_login_api_returns_token(session,client):
    form_data = {
        "username": "mike@gmail.com",
        "password": "mike"
    }
    response = client.post(  
        "/api/login", 
        data=form_data,
        headers={ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    )
    result = response.json()
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Getting {'detail': 'Not Found'} from result.

Comment: Can you add your endpoint code?

Comment: @code_10 I just updated it to use `json=` instead of `data=` can you try that?

Comment: Try setting headers to `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250929/discussion-between-code-10-and-enslaved-programmer).

Comment: this should use `data` instead of `json`, see https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/